# Searching in VSCode since the actual position

Tags: search, visual-studio-code, position

After a search, if founded, I would like the VSCode move to the next ocurrence, after my position, not to the first occurrence since the top of the code.
Is it possible? How?

Version 1.55.2

Comment: use the key `F3`

Comment: the first search. the cursor is automatically positioned on the first occurrence, even if I am after it ...

Comment: I have a file that has 40 occurrences of a word, I have the cursor before 20th occurrence, After Ctrl+F and typing the word, 20th occurrence if highlighted, with Return and F3 I can go to next occurrence and with Escape I get focus to the editor at the last found position

Comment: I agree. Should be the correct response, but using your example in my vscode, after Ctrl+F and typing the word, the 1st occurrence is highlighted, not the 20th occurrence...

Comment: try the VSC Insiders version without any settings modified